# Laravel 5.4 Checking given array from db

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.4

I'm trying to learn laravel and did some query. In this query, I'm trying to check if the values from the **Record** got the same *year* and *course* with the user.

```
$check1 = Record::where([['year','=',$show->year],['course','=',$show->course]])->get();
```

Since it is giving me a collection of array and wanted to check every single results that has been given, I have used a foreach.

```
foreach($check1 as $record){
    $check2 = Fbuser::where([['first_name','=',$record->firstname],['last_name','=',$record->lastname]])->get();
       if ($check2 === null) {
            dd($record->firstname);
       }else {
            //do something
       }}
```

In the code above, I was trying to check if the results from *$check1* exists on **Fbuser** table. NOW, the problem is it would only check the first value and not the rest. How can I make every results pass through *$check2* query? I thought for each would do the trick. Was planning to list all the names who aren't in the **Fbuser** table. Tried searching for a solution but can't seem to find one.

Comment: I see that you're not returning anything inside ur foreach, what is the reason behind the foreach?

Comment: @Sletheren I was trying to check every results from $check1. I was thinking for each would be of help.

Comment: check the answer below..you can do that using filter, filter will filter the result depending on what you want

Comment: Could you do that using only SQL?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Laravel's Filter, this will return only the Records that have a user with the same first_name and last_name:

```
$filtered_result = $check1->filter(function ($value, $key) {
    return Fbuser::where([['first_name','=',$value->firstname],['last_name','=',$value->lastname]];
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I have tried the solution but it seems like it's only returning me the logged in user's details. Weird. Probably on the way I did the query.

Comment: it has to return the Records where they match the FBuser first_name and last_name normally

Comment: yeah, but the logged in user isn't even on the FBuser table. Thanks for the solution tho, I've learned something new :)